# Foundation Columns when using Position:fixed forces an overlapp

Tags: css, zurb-foundation

I'm using foundation to create three sections of a site. Set up with the following html:

```
    <div class= "row full">
        <div class="sidebar large-2 columns">... </div>
        <div class="large-8 columns user-navbar">...</div>
        <div class="large-2 columns user-activity">...</div>
    </div>
```

I'm also trying to have the sidebar extend the vertical length of the page. I've been trying to do this by doing:

```
.sidebar {
    min-height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
}
```

However when I do this it provides an overlap of the user-navbar to the sidebar. Is there a way I can fix this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an older post that had a similar problem:

[Using fixed position with a grid layout framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9492045/using-fixed-position-with-a-grid-layout-framework)

For Foundation 6 which I'm working with, I added the class "large-offset-2" and it looks great now!

Answer (score 0):

there's no use of `position` here .So to extend height to window height use:

```
.sidebar {
    height: 100vh;

}
```

also define class sidebar as:

```
<div class="large-2 columns sidebar" style="background:red;height:120px">... </div>
```

Comment: The reason I didn't use 100vh is because if you make your window small, then scroll down to see content on the rest of the page, the sidebar stays at the window size and therefore won't exist when you scroll down.

Comment: @blueduckyy then use  min-height:100vh instead of height:100vh like this [https://jsfiddle.net/onafes9s/1/

Comment: I seem to have the same issue with min-height as I do with height. See this: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xqgwvB . If the window is small enough, the left pink column won't stay if you scroll down to see the bottom of the blue.

Comment: there is no content in the pink column thats why it won't stay if you add contents to it then it will retain pink background even in small screens during scrolling

Comment: I added some content. http://codepen.io/blueduckyy/pen/xqgwvB The issue is that the pink section will be a menu so it's not going to have as much content as the blue section but I want it to be available even if people scroll down.